# Finding data in nested dictionaries: TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am a begginner and am having some trouble with some piece of code. Would appreciate some help.

I have products for which I am trying to compare the prices in different websites. The trouble is that in each website the name of the product is slightly different. I have worked around that by creating a product mapping in excel with the names of the same products in different websites.

Now I want to create a spreadsheet with the format:

```
Product                    Price Website B            Price Website C
Product 1 Website A              $5.00                       $4.50
Product 2 Website A              $6.99                       $7.89
```

I have scraped the prices from the websites and created a spreadsheet with the website of origin, the name of the product on that website and the price on that website.

I am trying to do the following:

```
import openpyxl
import pprint

'''
Set up an empty dictionary which will have the following format:

data = {'product_name1_Website_A':
                {'product_name1_Website_B': price1_Website_B, 
                 'product_name1_Website_C': price1_Website_C
                },
        'product_name2_Website_A':
                {'product_name2_Website_B': price2_Website_B, 
                 'product_name2_Website_C': price2_Website_C
                },
        ...
            }

'''
data = {}

files = {'Name_Mapping':'Name_Mapping.xlsx',
         'Scan Prices':'price_scan.xlsx'
         }

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['Name_Mapping'])                   
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['Scan Prices'])                   

sheet1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Product Name Mapping')
sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

# Creating the dictionary structure.
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    prod_name_Website_A = sheet1['A' + str(row)].value
    prod_name_Website_B = sheet1['B' + str(row)].value
    prod_name_Website_C = sheet1['C' + str(row)].value
    data[prod_name_Website_A] = {}
    # Set default prices to zero for now
    data[prod_name_Website_A][prod_name_Website_B] = 0                          
    data[prod_name_Website_A][prod_name_Website_C] = 0                           

    # Search the spreadsheet containing the prices and bring those in 
    # to be added to dictionary.
    # I had to put this for loop inside the previous one because calling
    # data[prod_name_Website_A].values caused an issue due to local variable.
    for line in range(2, sheet2.max_row + 1):
        store = sheet2['A' + str(row)].value
        prod_name = sheet2['B' + str(row)].value
        price = sheet2['C' + str(row)].value
        if prod_name in data[prod_name_Website_A].values:
            data[prod_name_Website_A][prod_name] = price

pprint.pprint(data)
```

The line 'if prod_name in data[prod_name_Website_A].values:' generates an error:

TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Does anyone have any views on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[values](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/values) is a method on dictionaries, so the error your seeing here is python saying, you can't iterate on a method.

By calling the method however, it returns an iterator that allows you to do your if-in check.

```
if prod_name in data[prod_name_KN].values():
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe it was something so simple. The program ran with no errors, which is good. However the result is incorrect. I get the dictionary in the format I want, but all the prices are set to zero as per my default value. For some reason the "if prod_name in data[prod_name_Website_A].values()" line doesn't seem to be achieving what I am looking for. Do you have any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Actually eliminating the if statement all-together and just having data[prod_name_Website_A][prod_name] = price gives me the desired result. Thanks for the help with this.